# Emacs: How to keep the indentation level of a very long wrapped line

Tags: emacs, indentation, word-wrap

If there are lines in a file that are too long to be displayed on the screen, we can use word wrap. Now long lines are split into chunks visible on the screen.

Usually the code is structured and indenting is used for readability. If a line is wrapped into two (or more) lines, only the first line has right indenting and the other lines begin at the beginning of a row. Is there a way to **keep all of the wrapped lines with the same indent level** (**or more generally different indent level**)?

I have searched for a long long time, but still couldn't find a solution. This question is similar to a post for vim, but I didn't find a post or answer for emacs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The package [adaptive-wrap](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/adaptive-wrap.html), which can be installed via the [ELPA](http://elpa.gnu.org) packaging system, should do what you want.

After having installed the package, just run the following commands:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd>`visual-line-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd> (to wrap long lines)
- <kbd>M-x</kbd>`adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd> (to make wrapped lines indent nicely)

---

I also have the following snippet in my `init.el` file to automatically activate `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` along with `visual-line-mode`:

```lisp
(when (fboundp 'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)
  (defun my-activate-adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode ()
    "Toggle `visual-line-mode' and `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode' simultaneously."
    (adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode (if visual-line-mode 1 -1)))
  (add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook 'my-activate-adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode))
```

Comment: No need for an advice: you can use `visual-line-mode-hook` instead.

Comment: @Stefan Yes you're right. I got confused since `visual-line-mode-hook` is not documented as a variable and somehow I thought the mode did not setup any hook. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: One more question: when I try to print, the adaptive wrapping does not show up in the print out. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: I do not know about this, as a very seldom use Emacs' printing feature. Maybe you should ask another question...

Comment: Thanks still Francesco! I will post another question then. :)

Comment: Also in case people have the same confusion I had with adaptive wrap, adaptive wrap does not work when the beginning indentation contains tab, so you will need to use space only for indentation in order for it to work properly. It will be great if adaptive wrap can be more flexible in this respect.

Comment: Simplification: `(adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode (if visual-line-mode 1 -1))`

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin thanks, I edited the post to account for your comment.

Comment: Worth noting that to get wrap indicators one can use `(setq visual-line-fringe-indicators (quote (left-curly-arrow right-curly-arrow)))`

Comment: Is there a good reason against having these modes active as default?

Comment: @mcb I guess it's a matter of taste and buffer contents. For source code, I tend to break lines manually when needed. For LaTeX, I use auto-fill-mode to automatically break lines. I only use visual lines for some Markdown or Org buffers. But I don't think there would be any reason against always using these modes, except maybe for special buffers like dired or such.